# How can I increase space just above the footer line?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the space just above the footer line but I don't have the CSS for it.

[image]

Can you tell me how I increase the space on the page above the line? My html and [css](http://pastebin.com/rSLnFKN9) are pasted here:

```
<footer class="nohistory columns">



    <p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>


    <p>New Ads is the right choice for safe buying and selling in USA: a free classifieds website where you
        can buy and sell almost everything.</p>


    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free
        classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in
        your state or union territory.</p>


    <p>

        <strong>New Ads does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every
        ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why
        kewlbusiness is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in USA.</p>


    <div id="world_sites">





    </div>




</footer>
```

My full html is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords"
          content="Houses Apartments, Vacation homes, Offices, Land, Flatmates,Paying Guest, Other real estate, Cars, Motorcycles, Accessories  parts, Trucks, Other vehicles, Home  Garden, Clothing, For Kids (Toys  Clothes), Jewelry  Watches, Hobbies, Sports  Bicycles, Movies, Books  Magazines, Pets, Tickets, Art  Collectibles, Music  Instruments, Computers  Accessories, TV, Audio, Video, Cameras, Cellphones  gadgets, Video games  consoles, Job offers, Resumes, Services, Classes, Professional,Office equipment, Other,  ">
    <meta name="description"
          content="Find jobs, cars, houses, mobile phones and properties for sale in your region conveniently. Find the best deal among {{count}} free ads online!">

    <title>Free classifieds in India - new-ads.com</title>

    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?{VERSION}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?{VERSION}"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% include "kooltopbar.html" %}

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>


        function drawMap() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Province'],
       ['Montana'],
    ['Washington'],
    ['Oregon'],
    ['California'], // North West Frontier
    ['New York'],
    ['Connecticut'], // Northern Areas
    ['Alabama'],
    ['Idaho'], ['Nevada'],
    ['Nebraska'],
    ['Colorado'],
    ['Arizona'], // North West Frontier
    ['New Mexico'],
    ['Texas'], // Northern Areas
    ['Louisiana'],
    ['Oklahoma'],
       ['Virginia'],
    ['Kentucky'],
    ['Illinois'],
    ['Indiana'], // North West Frontier
    ['Arkansas'],
    ['Louisiana'], // Northern Areas
    ['Mississippi'],
    ['Georgia'], ['Florida'],
    ['Missouri'],
    ['Iowa'],
    ['Minnesota'], // North West Frontier
    ['South Dakota'],
    ['North Dakota'], // Northern Areas
    ['Wyoming'],
    ['Utah'],
    ['Illinois'],
    ['Maine'], // North West Frontier
    ['Vermont'],
    ['Massachussets'], // Northern Areas
    ['Maryland'],
    ['Delaware'], ['New Jersey'],
    ['South Carolina'],
    ['North Carolina'],
    ['Michigan'], // North West Frontier
    ['Wisconsin'],
    ['Kansas'], // Northern Areas
    ['Alaska'],
    ['Hawaii'],
    ['Rhode Island'],
    ['District of Colombia'], // North West Frontier
    ['Ohio'],
    ['West Virginia'], // Northern Areas
    ['Pennsylvania'],
    ['Tennessee'],
    ['New Hampshire']
    ]);

 var options = {
           region:'US',
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
      width:468,
       height:278,
     resolution: 'provinces',
        };
    var container = document.getElementById('mapcontainer');
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

    function myClickHandler(){
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        var message = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            var item = selection[i];
                message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
             if (item.row != null) {
                message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
            }
        }
        if (message == '') {
            message = 'nothing';
        }
        //alert('You selected ' + message);

        if (item.row==0) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8032183";
        }
        if (item.row==2) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8030183";
        }
        if (item.row==3) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8029183";
        }
        if (item.row==4) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D68033183";
        }
        if (item.row==6) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8028183";
        }
        if (item.row==7) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8031183";
        }
        if (item.row==5) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8032183";
        }
        if (item.row==1) {
             window.location = "/q?query=regionID%3D8031184";
        }
        if (item.row==10) {
             window.location = "/himachal_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==11) {
             window.location = "/jammu_kashmir/";
        }
        if (item.row==12) {
             window.location = "/jharkhand/";
        }
        if (item.row==13) {
             window.location = "/karnataka/";
        }
        if (item.row==14) {
             window.location = "/kerala/";
        }
        if (item.row==15) {
             window.location = "/madhya_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==16) {
             window.location = "/maharashtra/";
        }
        if (item.row==17) {
             window.location = "/manipur/";
        }
        if (item.row==18) {
             window.location = "/meghalaya/";
        }
        if (item.row==19) {
             window.location = "/mizoram/";
        }
        if (item.row==20) {
             window.location = "/nagaland/";
        }
        if (item.row==21) {
             window.location = "/orissa/";
        }
        if (item.row==22) {
             window.location = "/punjab/";
        }
        if (item.row==23) {
             window.location = "/rajasthan/";
        }
        if (item.row==24) {
             window.location = "/sikkim/";
        }
        if (item.row==25) {
             window.location = "/tamil_nadu/";
        }
        if (item.row==25) {
             window.location = "/tripura/";
        }
        if (item.row==28) {
             window.location = "/uttar_pradesh/";
        }
        if (item.row==29) {
             window.location = "/west_bengal/";
        }
        if (item.row==36) {
             window.location = "/andaman_nicobar_islands/";
        }
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
    chart.draw(data, options);
        }
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawMap});

     </script>

<div id="wrapper">

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- v2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
         data-ad-slot="9119838994"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>

 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
     data-ad-slot="4543980997"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>


<div class="main">
<div class="column_left">
    <div class="box">

        <ul>
            <li>New easy, free, and cool advertising.</li>
            <li>Buy and sell <a href="/us/cars-for_sale">cars</a>, check our <a href="/us/real_estate">real
                estate</a>
                section, find <a href="/us/jobs">jobs</a>, and much more.
            </li>
            <li>Check our <strong><a href="/us">{{count}} ads online</a></strong> and find what you are looking for
                in
                your region or in all USA.
            </li>
        </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="regions">


        <div class="region_links_one">
            <ul class="regions_one">
                <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7089183">Alabama</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7091183">Alaska</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7088186">Arizona</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7102183">Arkansas</a>
                </li>
  <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7095185">California</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7094186">Colorado</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7097187">Connecticut</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7088187">Delaware</a>
                </li>  <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7101184">Florida</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7090186">Georgia</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7095186">Hawaii</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7095187">Idaho</a>
                </li>  <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7101185"> Illinois</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7090187">Indiana</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7102184">Iowa</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7092184">Kansas</a>
                </li>  <li><a id="region_8" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7098186">Kentucky</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_9" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7100184">Louisiana</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_10" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7091184">Maine</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_11" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7089185">Maryland</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7096187">Massachusetts</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7096188">Michigan</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7098188">Minnesota</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7102185">Mississippi</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7094187">Missouri</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="regions_two">
 <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7093186">Montana</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7091185">Nebraska</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7102186">Nevada</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7093187">New Hampshire</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7090188">New Jersey</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7094188">New Mexico</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7099184">New York</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7101186">North Carolina</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7092185">North Dakota</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7098189">Ohio</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7091186">Oklahoma</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7097188">Oregon</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7088189">Pennsylvania</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7098190">Rhode Island</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7093188">South Carolina</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7094189">South Dakota</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7097189">Tennessee</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7101187">Texas</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7088189">Utah</a>
                </li>
                     <li><a id="region_12" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7088190">Vermont</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_13" class="region"
                       href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7097190">Virginia</a></li>
                <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7099185">Washington</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7091187">West Virginia</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a id="region_14" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7098191">Wisconsin</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="region_15" class="region" href="http://www.new-ads.com/q?query=regionID%3D7101188">Wyoming</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<div id="my_wrapper">

<div id="mapcontainer"></div>
<div id="gads" style="clear:both">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- frontpagebelowmap -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
     data-ad-slot="3839303791"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>



</div>
</div>



<footer class="nohistory columns">



    <p class="first">A good deal is just around the corner!</p>


    <p>New Ads is the right choice for safe buying and selling in USA: a free classifieds website where you
        can buy and sell almost everything.</p>


    <p><a href="/ai">Post an ad for free</a> or browse through our categories. You will find thousands of free
        classifieds for cars, houses, mobile phones and gadgets, computers, pets and dozens of items and services in
        your state or union territory.</p>


    <p>

        <strong>New Ads does not charge any fee and does not require registration.</strong> Every
        ad is checked so we can give you the highest quality possible for the ads on our site. That’s why
        kewlbusiness is the most convenient, easiest to use and most complete free ads site in USA.</p>


    <div id="world_sites">





    </div>




</footer>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: footer { margin-top: ##px; } ?

Comment: Provide me a full HTML doc. Your footer has already `margin-top` attribute, so it is supposed to work. It isn't working because something overwraps the footer's margin space. I can hardly pick up the factors by just looking at your CSS.

Comment: @hina10531 I've added the full html to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your css file

```
.nohistory {margin-top: 20px;}
```

or in html:

```
<footer class="nohistory columns" style="margin-top: 20px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

**YOU GOT TWO OPTIONS** to acheive this.

- **Get footer out of the main div** - *recommended* -
- It's not wrong to have a footer in a main section, but it's more explicit and makes sense in terms of HTML structure to have footer without any wrappers over it.
- [working example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/5jbLsq91/) ( sorry for the bad indentions in advance :[ )
- **Give padding-bottom on your** `column_left` **div**
- This can be a redundant workaround but, this is the best option if you don't want to reconstruct your HTML.
- [working example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zga67w4/)

---

**EXPLANATION**

Your footer has already `margin-top` attribute, but it doesn't push the elements up because they are already floating. A number of your elements inside of `column_left` have `float:left`. Well, what's important is that your `my_wrapper` is actually hanging on.